# How to Connect Pocket PC Emulator with Internet

Tags: connection, pocketpc

I have followed the steps provided in the following link to configure Pocket PC to Connect Internet: http://blog.rebex.net/news/archive/2009/01/28/howto-configuring-network-in-windows-mobile-pocketpc-device-emulator.aspx. Every thing Work fine , but when i tries to connect to internet it shows some error as follows:

[image]

Can any one tell me what , where it went wrong.... I followed the ablive mentioned steps in the URL.

Comment: What version of Windows are you on? What version of Compact Framework?

Answer (score 0):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289160(v=vs.71).aspx

scan on

Configuring the Emulator to Connect to the Internet

Comment: You should really describe the solution in the answer itself - see here for why: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7515/why-is-linking-bad